# ServerManager on .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to get access of windows API classes on .net core? For example i want to add web pages on IIS7 using c# ServerManager() method. The reference missing on .net core. Any idea how to do it in .net core?

Comment: With the entire point of .Net core being cross platform this would be platform specific code and defeat the purpose of core. You would need to use the full framework I believe or perhaps .Net Standard 2 (though I haven't attempted this).

Comment: The [`Microsoft.Web.Administration` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/) supports .NET Standard 1.6+, which .NET Core implements. Whether all of the features work is another matter, but `ServerManager` is available.